# regex python strip characters

Tags: python, regex

I have a text file:

```
z.server(y.host=>["x.012345","x.054321","x.045455"], :stop => 10)
z.server(y.host=>["x.067891","x.043215","x.045195"], :stop => 10)
z.server(y.host=>["x.012355","x.075321","x.045855"], :stop => 10)
```

I have a script which I want to extract the following data:

```
y.host 012345 012345 012345
y.host 067891 043215 045195
y.host 012355 075321 075321
```

When I run my python script I get:

```
y.host 012345","x.054321","x.045455
y.host 067891","x.043215","x.045195
y.host 012355","x.075321","x.045855
```

What am I missing?  Appreciate any help.

Here's my script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import re,sys

f = "test.txt"

rgxxid = re.compile('(^z\.\w+\((\w+\.\w+)=>\["x\.(\d+.*)"\]).\s+:\w+\s+=>\s\d+\)')

for l in open(f,'r').readlines():

   lm = re.match(rgxxid,l)

   if lm:

      hlm = lm.group(2)
      xid = lm.group(3)

      print hlm, xid

   else:
      sys.stderr.write("No XID match. "+l+"\n")
```

Comment: Will your text file always look like the above? It seems like you can circumvent using regex by just slicing the string.

Comment: Yes and no.  This is just a snippet of a much larger file.  For example, z.server and y.host will differ and there are hundreds of other lines of text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In brief, here is the problem with your current regex:

```
["x\.(\d+.*)"\]
         ^^^
```

The pattern `\d+.*` says to match one or more digits *followed by anything* up until the *last* quote.  What you are seeing in your output confirms this:

```
y.host 012345","x.054321","x.045455
```

The capture group has consumed everything until the end of the numbers list.  Instead, try using the following pattern:

```
^z\.\w+\((\w+\.\w+)=>\["x\.(\d+)","x\.(\d+)","x\.(\d+)"\],\s+:\w+\s+=>\s\d+\)
```

Here, I provide three explicit capture groups for each of the three numners.  Here is a demo for the regex:

## Demo

Your updated script should look something like this:

```
for l in open(f,'r').readlines():

lm = re.match(rgxxid,l)

if lm:

  term1 = lm.group(1)
  term2 = lm.group(2)
  term3 = lm.group(3)
  term4 = lm.group(4)

  print term1, term2, term3, term4

else:
  sys.stderr.write("No XID match. "+l+"\n")
```

Comment: Changing the regex in my script, I get these results.  012345 045455
067891 045195
012355 045855

Comment: @gineraso You need to print out _four_ capture groups per line, to cover the four terms you are trying to extract.

Comment: I updated my code with yours and I get the following error:  term4 = lm.group(4) IndexError: no such group.  If I remove the term4 line, it gives me: y.host 012345 045455, y.host 067891 045195, y.host 012355 045855.  This is closer to what I'm looking for but one of the columns is missing.

Comment: @gineraso Try my updated pattern.  I guess capture groups cannot be multiplied with Python regex.  The demo is also updated.

Comment: This worked.  Your updated pattern essentially looks for that pattern in groups 2-4.  If that line had 20 or more x.0***** in it would I need to repeat that pattern 20 times?

Comment: I'm not certain if there is a workaround.  My initial answer was trying to do that without success.  However, if all you want to do is verify the pattern, then I'm sure you can just repeat any pattern as you want.

Answer (score 2):

You might find it easier to use **pyparsing**. It definitely makes it simpler to capture the grammar of the lines that you have offered as examples.

Notice:

- What appear to be server names are defined as mixtures of alphabetic characters and periods. This could be expanded.
- The list could contain and retrieve an indefinite number of constants.

.

```
import pyparsing as pp

server = pp.Word(pp.alphas+'.')
item = pp.Suppress('"x.') + pp.Word(pp.nums) + pp.Suppress('"')
one_line = server.suppress() + pp.Suppress('(') + server + pp.Suppress('=>[') + item + pp.OneOrMore(pp.Suppress(',') + item)

lines = '''\
z.server(y.host=>["x.012345","x.054321","x.045455"], :stop => 10)
z.server(y.host=>["x.067891","x.043215","x.045195"], :stop => 10)
z.server(y.host=>["x.012355","x.075321","x.045855"], :stop => 10)'''

for line in lines.split('\n'):
    print (line)
    parsed = one_line.parseString(line)
    print ('\t', parsed[:5])
```

Output:

```
z.server(y.host=>["x.012345","x.054321","x.045455"], :stop => 10)
     ['y.host', '012345', '054321', '045455']
z.server(y.host=>["x.067891","x.043215","x.045195"], :stop => 10)
     ['y.host', '067891', '043215', '045195']
z.server(y.host=>["x.012355","x.075321","x.045855"], :stop => 10)
     ['y.host', '012355', '075321', '045855']
```